# (Stochastic Analysis) Computation Of A Particular Integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $W$ be a Brownian motion defined on an appropriate probability space. I wish to determine the value of
$$\int_0^t W_s^2\,dW_s$$
A partial solution follows: Let $f(x) = x^3/3$ and then apply Ito's Chain rule. Then,
$$df(W_t) = f(W_0) + W_t^2\,dW_t + W_t\,dt$$
$$W_t^3/3 = \int_0^tW_s^2\,dW_s + \int_0^t W_s\,ds$$
$$W_t^3/3 - \int_0^t W_s\,ds = \int_0^tW_s^2\,dW_s $$

My question is the following: Can any further simplification be carried out from here? I tried the following: Recall the integration by parts formula (for continuous processes)
$$X_tY_t = X_0Y_0 + \int_0^t X_s\,dY_s + \int_0^t Y_s\,dX_s + \langle X,Y \rangle_t $$
and now put $X = W$, and $Y_t = t$. Then, 
$$tW_t = \int_0^t W_s\,ds + \int_0^t s\,dW_s + \langle W_t,t \rangle_t$$

Comment: No, no further simplification is possible.